# Why is the elliptic curve given by $\sqrt[3]{z(z-1)}$ a double cover of the $z$-line?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In Bogomolov-Tschinkel's paper [Unramified Correspondences](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Etschinke/papers/yuri/02genram/genram.pdf), on page 3 they write:

Let $C_0\to E_0\to\mathbb{P}^1$ be the sequence of double covers induced by
$$\sqrt[6]{z(z-1)}\to \sqrt[3]{z(z-1)}\to z$$
Why is the second map a double cover? Looks like a triple cover to me?

Comment: To me too. Note that the authors are not renowned for their precision...

Comment: It seems clear to me that it's a triple cover, but what do I know?